# Pass Airflow params declared in the parent DAG to SUBDAG

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I want to pass params declared in parent dags to Subdag.
I verified if the data of params passed to subdag, but I don't find it in the context variable.
I worked with airflow V2.6.
This is an example of my code.

The parent DAG:

```
with DAG(
        dag_id=DAG_NAME,
        start_date=days_ago(1),
        default_args=default_args,
        
        params={
            "output": Param("TEST_OUTPUT_1" ,title="output folder", type="string"),
            "length": Param(100 ,title="length", type="integer", minimum=1),
            "load": Param("is_local", title="load", enum=["is_cloud", "is_local"]),
        },
) as dag:
    download_files= PythonOperator(
        task_id='download_files',
        python_callable=download_files,
    )

    section_2 = SubDagOperator(
        task_id="section-2",
        subdag=test_sub(DAG_NAME, "section-processing", dag.default_args),
    )
```

The subdag code:

```
def test_sub(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, default_args) -> DAG:
   
    
    with DAG(
            dag_id=f"{parent_dag_name}.{child_dag_name}",
            start_date=days_ago(1),
            catchup=False,
            schedule=None,
            default_args=default_args,
        ) as subdag:

        processing = PythonOperator(
            python_callable=processing_data,
            task_id='processing',
        )

        load_local_output = PythonOperator(
            python_callable=load_local_output,
            task_id='load_local_output',
        )

        processing >> load_local_output
```

How can I solve this problem?